# iOS How I can create cycle to check value in variable Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Problem is, when I start the app, app load data from server, but if something is not loaded I have empty variables, I try to use

while

But it goes to infinity cycle.
My code to check variables:

This method is calling in `viewWillAppear`

```
func checkVar() {
  if fullName.isEmpty == false || phoneNumber.isEmpty == false || emailLable.isEmpty == false == "" {
    displayActivityIndicatorAlert()
  }
}
```

Comment: Show displayActivityIndicatorAlert

Comment: My question was how to create cycle to check variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question:

> How i can create cycle to check value in variable Swift.

Answer: 
Don't do that.

You should not use a while loop on the main thread to check for an async event to complete.

Typically the API you use to fetch data from a server takes a completion handler and you'd put the code to update your UI in that completion handler. There are hundreds of threads here on SO explaining how to use completion handlers to handle responses from async APIs.

You'll need to provide a lot more information about the way you are reading data from your server if you want specific help getting your code to work, but the short answer is "Use a completion handler."

Comment: Can i get example?